# INSERT INTO нет реакции

Tags: php, mysql, sql

При отправке значения не вносятся в таблицу (в phpmyadmin запрос работает).

```
require 'config.php';    
mysql_connect(DATABASE,USERNAME,PASSWORD);    
mysql_select_db(DBNAME);   

$name = trim($_REQUEST['first_name']);    
$secondname = trim($_REQUEST['second_name']);    
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);    
$fb = trim($_REQUEST['facebook']);    
$twitt= trim($_REQUEST['twitter']);   
$pass = trim($_REQUEST['password']);    
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, second_name , email, facebook,twitter,password) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$secondname}', '{$email}', '{$fb}', '{$twitt}', '{$pass}')";    
mysql_query($insert_sql)    
or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: в начале файла: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); и посмотрите ошибку.

Comment: странно, die вам должен что то написать. он точно ничего никуда не пишет (может в логи какие нибудь, если уж на экране нет). И вас взломают минут через 10 как это заработает в интернете. подстановка текста получаемого в параметрах непосредственно в запрос чревата sql-инъекциями. Используйте более современные методы работы с БД (mysqli, PDO), вместо устаревшего лет 5 назад mysql_* и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: понимаю,но это лишь в обучающих целях, никакие проекты не делаю , только для себя х) а учебник экий нашёл по mysql.

Comment: там примерно то же самое функции называются практически так же. причем примеров для работы с БД в статьях по той ссылке что я привел достаточно для обучения. книги не нужны. привыкайте сразу работать на боле менее современном уровне. Ошибок на этапе выполнения при использовании привязки на порядок меньше, потому что не надо думать о том, где какие кавычки в запросе подставить (а 50% ошибок именно из за них).

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ниже вывод результирующей строки `$insert_sql` для начала.

Comment: Понял,извиняюсь если что не так,прислушаюсь.

Comment: Попробовал так , нечего не поменялось,ошибки нет. Результата тоже.

$insert_sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (first_name, second_name , email, facebook,twitter,password) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$secondname}', '{$email}', '{$fb}', '{$twitt}', '{$pass}')");
if (!insert_sql){
  echo ". mysql_error() ."
}

Answer (score 0):

ну, во-первых, сделайте `echo $insert_sql;`, возможно, что-то в запросе собирается криво... там часто нежданчики бывают, поэтому, даже если кажется, что все правильно - проверить надо...

во-вторых, может быть автокоммит выключен? попробуйте принудительно закоммитить транзакцию, т.е. после своего запроса (ну т.е. в конец того фрагмента скрипта, который вы прислали, добавьте `mysql_query('COMMIT;') or die (mysql_error());`

в-третьих, закройте коннект после завершения работы с БД... чисто теоретически, незакрытый коннект может привести к несостоятельности запроса... в стандартных конфигурациях и без фреймворков я такого не встречал, но я ж не знаю, чего у вас там вокруг скрипта... `mysql_close();`

хотя, если по-феншую, то надо везде id ресурса использовать... но подробнее об этом не буду, т.к. совсем по-феншую - mysql из php вообще надо использовать через PDO (ну в крайняк - через mysqli).  Но это уже - оффтоп.